# bi publisher printing error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, bi-publisher, oracle-apex-5.1

im using bi publisher add-in on ms word ...when i tried to print a report in oracle apex 5.1 an error appeared 
ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached because either the URL specified is incorrect or a proxy URL needs to be specified.
as i found some solutions here on stack overflow so i tried run this on sqlplus command line connected as sysdba

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_050100
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_050100 does not have the privilege yet.

  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050100',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050100', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
    'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
    'APEX_050100', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;

DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to 'localhost' and give     APEX_050100
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_040200 does not have the privilege yet.
  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = 'localhost' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050100',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050100', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to 'localhost'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('local-access-users.xml',
    'ACL that lets users to connect to localhost',
    'APEX_050100', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('local-access-users.xml','localhost');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

after i execute i tried again to print the report and then the following error occured:

```
Error occurred while painting error page: ORA-01403: no data found ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1324 ORA-12570: TNS:packet reader failure
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all ORA-20001 is a user-defined error.

I only re-ordered the first block. Changed the order of statements. Put exception just after `select` statement. Since, when exception occurs, `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE` wouldn't run in your case.

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_050100
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_050100 does not have the privilege yet.
  BEGIN
      SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

    EXCEPTION
         -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
              DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
             'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
             'APEX_050100', TRUE, 'connect');
             DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
  END;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050100',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050100', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;
END;
/
COMMIT;
```